# Javascript coding problem when I want to add balance from withdraw input

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, bank

I am trying to change the amount of withdraw balance when I click withdraw button. But when I click withdraw button, only the withdraw amount changes. Where is the problem? The deposit button works fine. Please check my code.
code link : https://basir5101.github.io/ta-ta-bank/
repository link: https://github.com/basir5101/ta-ta-bank/blob/master/index.html/

Comment: Post the relevant code here, not at an external repository.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On withdrawal you are updating the withdraw wallet amount which is perfect, But you are not updating the `currentBalance` wallet. Have added the extra line for updating current balance when you update withdraw, now it's working fine:

```
withdrawButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const withdrawInput = document.getElementById('withdrawInput').value;
    const withdrawInputNumber = parseFloat(withdrawInput);
    console.log(withdrawInputNumber);
    balance('currentWithdraw', withdrawInputNumber);
    balance('currentBalance', withdrawInputNumber);

    document.getElementById('withdrawInput').value = "";
})
```